# ClassNotFound exception despite every file is correct

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml, servlet-3.0

I have this JSP form:

```
<form action="SearchData" method="post">
   Name:  <input name="name" size="20" />
   <input type="submit"   value="Search">
</form>
```

The following is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <display-name>MongoWebPrj01</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>Welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>SearchData</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>MongoWebPrj01.SearchData</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>SearchData</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/SearchData</url-pattern>  <!-- This is the URL of the servlet. 
-->
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And here is a part of the servlet code:

```
@WebServlet("/SearchData")
public class SearchData extends HttpServlet {
 @SuppressWarnings("null")
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
```

I am getting classnotfound excpetion despte trying all things.

What could possibly be I missing in the code?
Everything seems fine to me but still it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT:

[image]

STACKTRACE:

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet SearchData
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MongoWebPrj01.SearchData
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please include the actual exception in your question.

Comment: Either configure the servlet using `<servlet>` element in `web.xml`, *or* configure it using `@WebServlet` annotation. Don't do both.

Comment: I see no `package MongoWebPrj01;` statement in the source of your `SearchData` class. I see no file structure showing your files, so are we supposed to trust that "every file is correct" is actually true. How do you *know* that to be so?

Comment: Have you had a chance to learn about source vs. compiled files?  How do you build this?  How do you deploy it?  I see the source code but I don't see your deployed project.

Comment: @Andreas  Could you explain "configure the servlet using <servlet> element in web.xml, or configure it using WebServlet annotation" ?
Also a relevant tutorial explaining tomcat,servers, web.xml files, build, build path, deployment, war files and functioning of web app projects??
Thanks in advance

Comment: @MOngoDBUser [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)